# How do you add a category to a post in code

Tags: categories

We do a lot of post maintenance outside of the WordPress interface and as a result we need ways of categorising posts. Obviously Wordpress has categories (aka taxonomies) on posts and I plan on using them, but haven't found a way that I can do that in code.

We also use custom post types extensively so the accepted answer may need to state how to incorporate categories into them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's the `wp_update_post()`, also.

According to categories, please refer to the [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post).

> Categories need to be passed as an array of integers that match the
>   category IDs in the database. This is the case even where only one
>   category is assigned to the post.

So, it would be something like:

```
$post = get_post($i = $post_id);
$post->post_category = array ($cat1, $cat2, $cat3);
wp_update_post($post);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for, along with get_the_category() to iterate through and get the category ID

Comment: Can you tell me how can I insert a whole category into the specific post.
for example: have 4 posts in a category "zanimljivosti" and I want to put that category to be shown inside another post not as a link but to show all 4 inside that new post. Can I do that?

Comment: For anyone reading this now (2014), you don't seem to be able to use the `post_category` anymore - you need to use wp_set_post_terms() (eg. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8913082/categories-not-updating-with-wp-update-post).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do just about everything you're looking to do between [`wp_insert_post()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post), [`wp_set_object_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms), and [`wp_insert_term()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term). Those all work well with custom post types and custom taxonomies. If you can be a bit more specific about any issues you're encountering (possibly in a new question...depending how far off it is from this one) someone should be able to provide example code.